# How to add unlimit clicks of adding border

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

i want that every time user will click the square it will add the extra border class and not just 1 time as it for now

here is the fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/mtrh5/34/

example code:

```
 $('.box').on('click', function changeBoreder() {
        $(this).addClass('addborder');
    });
```

Comment: How can you add a class twice? Styles don't add, they only override each other. Are you just trying to make the border progressively thicker with each click?

Comment: having class="addborder addborder addborder" does not change anything, the border won't get any bigger. Instead, you have to increase the border, not add CSS class

Comment: @Overcode yes exactly

Comment: Do you mean `var cnt=5;
$('.box').on('click', function() {
    $(this).css("border",(cnt++)+"px solid black");
});`

Comment: @alonblack - I recommend you check out the .css() method instead of the addClass() one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add a class twice.
Styles aren't meant to add onto each other, they override each other.

Instead, modify the border yourself.
`var border = 0;`

and then in the click event

```
border += 5;
$(this).css("border", border+"px solid black");
```

Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mtrh5/35/)

Comment: Or you could just change the border-width CSS property.

Answer (score 2):

```
var borderStep = 5;

$('.box').on('click', function changeBoreder() {
    var borderWidth = parseInt($(this).css('border-width'));
    borderWidth += borderStep;
    $(this).css({'border-width':borderWidth+'px'});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mtrh5/42/

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do something like this using [**css()**](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```
var px = 1;
$('.box').on('click', function changeBoreder() {
   px++;
   $(this).css("border", px + "px solid #000000");
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mtrh5/40/)

Comment: Sorry brother, that won't work. Because solid needs to be placed in the middle and the px thing should come in the middle! :) Edit it..

Answer (score 1):

That doesnot work, because even if you keep clicking on it multiple times the result will be same. Because the class is same and will have just one effect.

What you can do is to enlarge the border. By using the current value, and adding it some your own value as:

```
var valuess = parseInt($(this).css('border-width'),10);
// now the code runs and updates it
valuess += 5;
$(this).css('border', valuess + 'px solid #333');
```

This code will get the current border's width and then replace the `px` part and remove it. After that it will add `5` to it as a string that is why the border gets to be 55 instead of 10. Sorry about that bro hehehe. But that is the code that you need! :) Good luck

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/mtrh5/39/

Comment: It doesn't blow the screen, it is because of 5 being changed to 55.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you can do...

```
 var border = 5;  ///Set the boprder to default 5
 $('.box').on('click', function changeBoreder() {
    $(this).css("border", + border +"px solid black"); // Set the css border to the current element
    border = border + 5; // Increase the value of border by 5..or whatever value you want. So that every time you click it increases the value
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mtrh5/37/

Comment: this is great, can u explain to me why i need "border = border + 5;" if we difined "varvar border = 5;" from the beginning?

Comment: @alonblack you can have a look at my code :) It is explained and has a fiddle to test too..

Comment: In order to increment the value of border to increase every time you click...So first time you click it'll be 5 then it increases the value of border to 10, so next time you click it'll set the css to 10px ...and so on... Hope this helps...